# Values not coming in Dropdown in PowerBuilder 12.5.2

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder-conversion

I have recently migrated to PB 12.5 from PB 10.5. I am facing an issue now in PB 12.5 where i try to fetch the values in Drop down which is placed on a Data window. As of today i have below code in place where i first insertrow in Data window and then establish SQLCA connection. This used to work fine in PB 10.5 but it stopped working with PB 12.5. When i debug the code and i execute the statement for establishing SQLCA connection first then insertrow it works fine with PB 12.5 but not the other way round.

```
dw_5.InsertRow(0)
dw_5.SetTransObject (SQLCA)
```

How i can resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'values in a Drop down' my assumption is a drop down datawindow (dddw) column in a datawindow which itself is populated by another datawindow object which retrieves values from the database.

You need to establish the database connection prior to inserting the row.  This is how it should have been done in your v10.5 code.

Alternatively you can use the GetChild method on the dddw column in your dw_5, set the transaction object on the child datawindow, then issue a retrieve on the child dw prior to inserting the row in the parent dw (dw_5 in your example).